# Convert an Array of Bytes to IPAddress

Tags: .net, ip-address

.Net IPAddress class GetAddressBytes method can be used to convert an IPAddress to an array of bytes.

My problem is one I have these array of bytes, how do I convert them back to an IPAddress object, or an IP string??
(Its important to have a solution working for both IPv4 and IPv6).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [IPAddress Constructor (Byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4k07yby.aspx)

Comment: Hmm... Wonder how I meed that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What andrey said

```
    Dim ipv4Addr As Net.IPAddress = Net.IPAddress.Parse("224.0.0.1")
    Dim ipv6Addr As Net.IPAddress = Net.IPAddress.Parse("ff00:0:0:0:0:0:e000:1")

    Debug.WriteLine(ipv4Addr.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine(ipv6Addr.ToString)

    Dim b() As Byte = ipv4Addr.GetAddressBytes
    ipv4Addr = New Net.IPAddress(b)

    b = ipv6Addr.GetAddressBytes
    ipv6Addr = New Net.IPAddress(b)

    Debug.WriteLine(ipv4Addr.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine(ipv6Addr.ToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

@dbasnett's answer in C#

```
            IPAddress ipv4Addr = IPAddress.Parse("224.0.0.1");
            IPAddress ipv6Addr = IPAddress.Parse("ff00:0:0:0:0:0:e000:1");

            Console.WriteLine(ipv4Addr.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ipv6Addr.ToString());

            byte[] b = ipv4Addr.GetAddressBytes();
            ipv4Addr = new IPAddress(b);

            b = ipv6Addr.GetAddressBytes();
            ipv6Addr = new IPAddress(b);

            Console.WriteLine(ipv4Addr.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ipv6Addr.ToString());
```